# How to build angular application on centos server

Tags: angular, centos7

I am trying to build an angular project on server (Centos 7).I get this error :

"ERROR in src/app/shared/Entities/userDefinedFields.entity.ts:1:43 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './UserDefinedFieldGroup.entity'.

1 import {UserDefinedFieldGroupEntity} from './UserDefinedFieldGroup.entity';"

When i do this locally (windows 10) it works fine and it creates the dist folder.

For both operations i am using :

node -v ==> v10.23.0

npm -v ==> 6.14.8

ng --version ==> CLI: 9.1.12

Comment: Don't know why this happens but try to give extension too `userDefinedFields.entity.ts`. This may not help but give it a try.

Comment: An import path cannot end with a '.ts' extension. Consider importing './UserDefinedFieldGroup.entity' instead.

Comment: Linux and Windows differ in case sensitivity. Are you sure you have the right casing on your filename?

Comment: share a screenshot of your directory structure. Does both ts files are on same dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux and windows differ in filesystem case-sensitivity. Make sure the filename passed exactly matches the casing of the file.

Comment: i changed "UserDefinedFieldGroup.entity" to "userDefinedFieldGroup.entity" and it worked.It was a problem due to case-sensitivity.